# Is there a way to have a resque job push a generated pdf directly to the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn, faye

I need to have a system where a PDF is generated dynamically, asynchronously, and directly pushed to the browser, no disk storage is available. Getting resque to use prawn seems easy, its taking that data and sending it to the browser without storing it somewhere first, I can't find anything online. I thought about Faye, but can Faye handle pushing a PDF to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before in .net where i have an iframe's src attribute set to a service that returns a stream.  The service aslo flips the http header to content-inline so that the browser doesn't try to download it but instead will try to render it inline.  If you try to do this it wont work if the browser doesn't have a pdf plugin (must modern ones will but you always have that guy using IE6 yet)  I don't know  a lick of ruby but think you should be able to do something similar, or at least but an iframe on a page that targets a service written in something else.

Answer (score 0):

u can use "PDFkit" for it. 
the sample code is

```
def some_action
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      generate_pdf(file.html.haml, :css => [array of css file names that need to be added])
    end
  end
end
```

in application controller -

```
def generate_pdf(template, options={})
  html = render_to_string(template, :layout => false)
  kit = PDFKit.new(html, :orientation => 'Landscape')
  kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/default_css1.css"
  kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/default_css2.css"

  # Add CSS
  if options[:css]
    options[:css].each do |css|
      kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/#{css}.css"
    end
  end

  send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'latest.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
end
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem, these PDFs can take up to 20-30 minutes to generate. I cannot have Unicorn keeping an open HTTP connection for that long, it needs to be done as a background job and then streamed to the user once its completed. Nor am I allowed even temporary storage for these files.

Comment: It seems to me, that I must be very horrible at communicating the problem. I already am using rescue, I am using prawn... thats not the issue. The issue is once I have made a pdf in resque, how do I get that back to the browser? As said before I CANNOT STORE THE PDF, IT MUST REMAIN IN MEMORY THE ENTIRE TIME! This is a hard requirement, the client will not budge.

Comment: 1) if ur pdf file takes to much time to generate, its better to generate it in the background(so that the server doesnt time out.). hence 'delayed_job'. 2) u dont want the pdf to be saved but want to inform the user that its ready to download when its generated. hence "send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'latest.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')". it will give a popup to user asking if he wants to donwload it(the popup depends upon browser settings too)

Comment: u cant keep the pdf in the memeory cause if it exceeds the memory, it application may malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

How big those PDFs are? Your database has BLOB columns (if you don't have storage, you are not using SQLite...) and you can store the resulting PDF in it.

Or you can store the resulting PDF in the Redis DB. Or save it in S3.

On the other end, the browser will be polling (with ajax) every now and then to know whether the PDF is complete, and as soon as it is ready it will download it and show it to the user.

Comment: But thats the thing... I can't find anywhere on google how to poll a resque job with ajax. And its not the size of the individual PDF, its that we don't have space to store one per user... we have a lot of users. What I would like to do is send the PDF over something like Faye, but I can't find anything in Faye that suggests it can handle a PDF.

Comment: Can Redis handle storing the file as temporary cache? I heard Redis is not good for large data.